# AWS route traffic destined to NLB to firewall instance in same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, nlb, routetable, fortigate

I have a fortigate `ec2` instance in public subnet. An `eks` cluster in public subnet application deployed in `eks` is accessible using `NLB` endpoint in public subnet. I want all the traffic to my application pass through the fortigate firewall(fortigate instance and `NLB` are in same public subnet).
So I have tried configuring route table for public subnet or the edge route table for internet gateway so if traffic is destined to `NLB` private interface ips it should be routed to fortigate vm interface but got the error that it's not a subnet cider.
I only want incoming traffic to pass through fortigate so I can setup some firewall rules on it.
Can anyone help with this config or suggest any better way to implement the desired requirement.

I have tried with `NLb` interface `ips` and also tried creating a prefix list from private ips but nothing worked

Editing the question as cannot post this in comment

So I have did the same config for subnets as mentioned in 1st awnser.  Also created fortigate VM with two interfaces port1 in public and port2 in NLB subnet. And For egde subnet sending the traffic to port2 interface same for internet traffic of NLB subnet. Here is the fortigate config file

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==AWS=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--==AWS==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0

config system interface
edit port1
set vdom "root"
set alias public
set mode dhcp
set allowaccess ping https ssh fgfm
next
edit port2
set vdom "root"
set alias private
set mode dhcp
set allowaccess ping https ssh fgfm probe-response
next
end
config firewall policy
edit 1
set name "test"
set srcintf "port1"
set dstintf "port2"
set srcaddr "all"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ALL"
set logtraffic all
next
edit 1
set name "test2"
set srcintf "port2"
set dstintf "port1"
set srcaddr "all"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ALL"
set logtraffic all
next
end
config router static
    edit 1
        set gateway ${nlb_ip}
        set device "port1"
    next
    edit 2
        set gateway ${nlb_ip}
        set device "port2"
    next
end

--==AWS==--
```

Still when hit the nlb endpoit it is not reachable. but if use normal network config without fortigate is accessable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to route traffic through an intermediate device like the setup you mentioned, its better to have them in separate Subnets. If the routing is expected to be as below:

`Client --> Internet --> IGW --> Fortigate --> NLB --> EKS`

You will need to spilt them to at least 2 subnets.

1. Public subnet to hold your Fortigate FW ENIs
2. Protected subnet where you can host your NLBs (and EKS)

Route-Tables will be as below:

---

**Public Subnet's Route-Table:**

VPC CIDR **>** local

0.0.0.0/0 **>** IGW

---

**Protected Subnet's Route-Table:**

VPC CIDR **>** local

0.0.0.0/0 **>** FW ENI

---

**Edge Route-Table(** *on IGW* **):**

VPC CIDR **>** local

NLB's Subnet CIDR **>** FW ENI

Comment: Edited question for the new issue.

Comment: @AdeelShahzad Looks like you are using the NLB's IP as gateway which is not required. You will only need rules to allow the traffic. Is the FortiGate performing a NAT on the incoming traffic ? Noticed that you are using a 2-arm deployment. So the NLB's subnet route table should have `0.0.0.0/0 > FW Port 2` . And on the Edge route table it should having `NLB's Subnet CIDR > FW Port 1`

To add to the above setup, this FW will can be a single point of failure in this setup. Having a Gateway Load Balancer with one-arm more is better in this case

Comment: I am a little confused about traffic flow why `0.0.0.0/0 > FW PORT 2` required. Like through edge route table traffic is already moving to FW. why not sent 
 egress traffic to IGW from NLB subet?
And if I do one arm deployment should it be in public subnet with port1 only? what will happen to port2?

Comment: From NLB, the egress traffic (i.e. the response packets inlcuding SYN-ACK) will need to take the path through the firewall.  If not, FW will only get to see one side of the traffic and is termed as  `asymmetric routing`. Firewalls work effectively when it gets to see both side traffic. 

**Ingress flow**: Client --> Internet --> IGW --> FW Port 1 --> [FW Engine]  --> FW Port 2 --> NLB --> EKS

**Egress flow**: EKS --> NLB --> FW Port 2 --> [FW Engine]  --> FW Port 1 --> IGW --> Internet --> Client

Comment: OK I got it but is their anything wrong with this config because i tried the same thing you have mentioned but still nothing is working. or somehow I can check how traffic is flowing like logs in fortigate.

Comment: @AdeelShahzad In FW you will need to check for 2 things, 1) Policy to Allow the access & 2) NAT Rules. In this communication you are trying, NAT should use the same IP since you are using public NLB. Won't be able to cover the settings needed on firewall to let this through. You can use VPC Flow logs to confirm whether client packets are reaching the FW Port 1 and then leaving towards NLB using Port 2. If the second is not seen, packets are not getting through and check on FW application will be needed. An additional check is to disable "source/destination check" in the FW instance